# $\frac{d}{dt}H\bigl(t,u(t),v(t)\bigr)$, does introductory calculus books introduce such chain rule?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $H$ be a real-valued function with three variables, $u,v$ be two real-valued functions with one variable. If we're asked to compute $$\frac{d}{dt}H\bigl(t,u(t),v(t)\bigr)$$
The tree diagram may seem like this:
[image]

However, the left most branch directly connects to the node $H$, which is a case of tree diagram that is not easily seen in the introductory calculus books. In these books, the trees often appears more "regular". So how to compute the result by this unusual tree?

In a more complicated way, how about to compute the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ of $F\bigl(~~g(x,~h(y)),~~\phi(x,y,z)~~\bigr)$?

(Btw, I come from the background of real-analysis, thus the way to compute chain rule that I accustomed to is to use the matrix version $[Df(g(\mathbf{x}))]=[Df(g(\mathbf{x}))][Dg(\mathbf{x})]$, which is easy to remember and clear to compute. However, I just found it often too 'slow' to figure out which term we need.. So I think I should go back to use the introductory calculus way...)

Comment: No usually this is not dealt in a first course of calculus. The necessary ingredients for this kind of chain rule are provided in multi variable calculus and it involves notion of partial derivatives and total derivatives.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh, I see. For "calculus", I mean the whole books of, say Ron Larson's, Howard Anton's, etc. (i.e., the textbooks with almost 1000 up pages.)

Comment: If some book covers multivariable calculus then this scenario will be covered there. For your specific example we have $$\frac{dH} {dt} =\frac{\partial H} {\partial x} +\frac{\partial H} {\partial y} \frac{du} {dt} +\frac{\partial H} {\partial z} \frac{dv} {dt} $$ assuming $H=H(x, y, z) $. After the evaluation of partial derivatives you need to replace $x, y, z$ by $t, u(t), v(t) $ respectively.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Hmm.. is the essence here we actually thinking of the left most branch as $H\circ\text{id}(t)$, where $\text{id}$ means identity function? I feel if thinking as so, then it can still corresponding to the traditional basic pattern of chain rule in calculus books. However, it's somewhat redundant to think via identity function.. Or is it better to directly think about it, without involving any identity function?

Comment: You are correct. Indeed the first branch involves identity function.

Comment: Is identity function here really inevitable? Is it similar that in $F(~x,y,g(x,y)~)$ (where $x,y$ are variables), the real things happen in the first coordinate is $\pi_1(x,y)$?

Comment: Your first $Df(g(\mathbf{x}))$ must be $D(f\circ g)(\mathbf{x})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, write it fully:
$$
t\longmapsto\pmatrix{t\cr u(t)\cr v(t)}\longmapsto H\pmatrix{t\cr u(t)\cr v(t)}
$$
Let be $F$ the "inner" function:
$$H(t,u(t),v(t)) = H(F(t)) = (H\circ F)(t).$$
By the chain rule:
$$D(H\circ F)(t) = DH(F(t))DG(t) = DH(F(t))G'(t).$$
$$
((\partial_x H)(F(t)),(\partial_y H)(F(t)),(\partial_z H)(F(t)))
\pmatrix{1\cr u'(t)\cr v'(t)} = \cdots
$$
Edit:

$\partial_x(F(g(x,h(y)),\phi(x,y,z)))$, i.e., the derivative of 
$x\longmapsto F(g(x,h(y)),\phi(x,y,z))$:
$$x\longmapsto
\pmatrix{g(x,h(y))\cr\phi(x,y,z)}\longmapsto
F\pmatrix{g(x,h(y))\cr\phi(x,y,z)}
$$
$$D(F\circ J)(x) = DF(J(x))DJ(x) = DF(J(x))J'(x) =$$
$$((\partial_1 F)(g(x,h(y)),\phi(x,y,z)),(\partial_2 F)(g(x,h(y)),\phi(x,y,z)))
\pmatrix{(\partial_x g)(x,h(y))\cr(\partial_x\phi)(x,y,z)} = \cdots
$$

Comment: Thanks. I see. I want to ask that in daily need of compute such version or other possibly more complicated version of chain rule, do you use the "tree diagram" method or matrix method to aid for writing all involving terms correctly?

Comment: @Eric, I've never used tree diagrams. Use it if you want. In this case you only need a new branch $t - t$ and your tree will be "regular".

Comment: I sometimes feel the matrix diagrams to slow to find out the formula when the number of variables of the composite function is $\geq2$ or the composite function is vector-valued . For example, to figure out what is the result of $\partial_x F\bigl(~~g(x,~h(y)),~~\phi(x,y,z)~~\bigr)$ would take me 1 minute. Is their a useful/clever way to accelerate the matrix way and prevent from using the tree diagram?

Comment: @Eric, in *this* case (only $\partial_x$ required) you can use that $y$, $z$ are constants. In general, I don't know any shortcut, but the matrix method is essentially a trivial mechanic procedure. If you want, I will write   the solution tomorrow. BTW, better write $\partial_x (F\bigl(~~g(x,~h(y)),~~\phi(x,y,z)~~\bigr))$: partial derivative of the composed function ($\ne$ partial derivative of $F$ evaluated at...)

Comment: Oh, I see. If you have time tomorrow, hope that you can help me. Thanks! :)